# XSLT: Matching Xpath attributes to attributes from for-each scope

Tags: xslt, scope, foreach

I guess my problem is quite common, so there must be an easy solution. Consider the following xml snippet:

```
  <categories>
    <category name="cat1" />
    <category name="cat2" />
    <category name="cat3" />
    <category name="cat4" />
  </categories>
  <data>
    <catval name="cat2">foo</catval>
    <catval name="cat4">bar</catval>
    <catval name="cat3">boo</catval>
  </data>
```

I need to output the catval values in the order defined in the categories element (including categories that have no data). Please note that in the real input xml, there are multiple *data* elements all over the place and the output is way more complex, so creating a template for *categories* is not feasible. I am using a construct like the following:

```
<xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:variable name="currentdata" select="." />
    <xsl:for-each select="../categories/category">
      <xsl:value-of select="@name" />: 
      <xsl:value-of 
        select="$currentdata/catval[@name=@name]" /> <!-- ??? -->
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I don't know if this is the best approach to solve my problem, but even if it isn't: How can I match the *name* attribute of $currentdata/catval to the *name* attribute of the *category* element in the context of the for-each loop?

Comment: Edit: I didn't mention before that there might be multiple data elements in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable to save the attribute value from the `<xsl:for-each>` scope:

```
<xsl:template match="data">
  <xsl:variable name="currentdata" select="." />
  <xsl:for-each select="../categories/category">
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="@name"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$name" />: 
    <xsl:value-of 
      select="$currentdata/catval[@name=$name]" /> <!-- ??? -->
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Didn't think of that, thank you. But is this really the only way do do it? To me it seems odd enough that I need a variable to refer to the scope outside the for-each loop...

Comment: I believe you can use the `current()` function for that, so that you could write: `<xsl:value-of select="$currentdata/catval[@name=current()/@name]"/>`
I admit that one always confuses the hell out of me, because most of the time `current()` is the same as `.` except when it's not :) So I stick to storing the value in a var.

Comment: One thing I'd like to point out: there is no checking to see of all catval items are actually visited, even if the order is not defined. I hope that's ok...

Comment: Only the defined categories should be shown, so this is correct for me.

Answer (score 3):

Simple, elegant and efficient:

```
<xsl:key name="catvalByName" match="catval" use="@name" />

<xsl:template match="category">
  <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
  <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="key('catvalByName', @name)" />
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Would output:

```
cat1: 
cat2: foo
cat3: boo
cat4: bar
```

when called like this, for example:

```
<xsl:template match="categories">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="category" />
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go the other way:

```
<xsl:template match="categories">
   <xsl:for-each select="category">
     <xsl:variable name="name" select="@name"/>
     <xsl:apply-template select="/data/catval[@name=$name]/>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="catval">
  <!-- Your output logic here -->
</xsl:template>
```

So, once you're in the "catval" template, you're sure the ordering is already done and you just have to focus on the output formatting.

Comment: yeah this is nicer. I should've read more carefully. There is one thing though, that I didn't think of either...there is no checking to see of all catval items are actually visited, even if the order is not defined.

Comment: I would do this, but in the real xml there are multiple *data* elements all over the place but just one definition of the categories at the top.

Comment: Ok, in that case, you migth also consider using the <key> element, to grab all <data> element in the document.